# magento custom shipping method error

Tags: magento

I have tried to create duplicate flat rate shipping from below tautorial 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/duplicating_flat_rate_shipping_module

After that when i refresh the page and add shpping address it to goes to blank page.

When i check the log file it say

```
2015-02-10T04:12:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/12/107171/webspace/httpdocs/yangfanau.com/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrateuk.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/vhosts/12/107171/webspace/httpdocs/yangfanau.com/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

Currently i am using magento 1.9.0.1 version and different theme

Comment: Got it 

We need to create file in Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrateuk.php in inclide/src folder for one page checkout

Comment: you don't need to create file include/src folder. you need to disable the compilation and enable it once again. files copied automatically.

Comment: ok one more error i have deleted the file and also delete entries from table core_config_data

Now when click on continue button after filling shipping adress on check out page it again goes to cart page can you help me

    POST http://yangfanau.com/en/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/ 500 (Internal Server Error) prototype.js:1530

Comment: Ajax.Request.Class.create.request prototype.js:1530
Ajax.Request.Class.create.initialize prototype.js:1495
(anonymous function) prototype.js:429
klass prototype.js:101
Billing.save opcheckout.js:372
onclick (index):618

    My site url: http://yangfanau.com/ 

can you help me why this happen it working fine before i configure the new duplicate flat rate module

Comment: Cheers
 i have syntax error in page thats why it load cart page again